# If $\phi$ is a homeomorphism and both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ extend to differentiable functions, is ${\rm D}\phi(x)$ invertible?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, frechet-derivative, diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

Let $k,d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, $U\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ and $\phi:\Omega\to U$ be a homeomorphism and $\psi:=\phi^{-1}$. Assume $$\phi=\left.\tilde\phi\right|_\Omega\tag1$$ for some $\tilde\phi\in C^1(O,\mathbb R^k$ for some $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $O$ of $\Omega$ and $$\psi=\left.\tilde\psi\right|_V\tag2$$ for some $\tilde\psi\in C^1(V,\mathbb R^d$ for some $\mathbb R^k$-open neighborhood $V$ of $U$.

> Let $x\in\Omega$ and $u:=\phi(x)$. Are we able to show that ${\rm D}\phi(x)$ and ${\rm D}\psi(u)$ are bijective? If not, are we at least able to show that ${\rm D}\phi(x)$ is surjective and ${\rm D}\psi(u)$ is injective?

My problem with this task is that I think we would need, for example, that $\tilde\psi\circ\tilde\phi$ is the identity map when restricted to an **open** subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

Clearly, since $\Omega\subseteq O$ and $U\subseteq V$, $\tilde\phi$ is differentiable at $x$ and $\tilde\psi$ is differentiable at $u:=\tilde\phi(x)=\phi(x)\in U$. Thus, $\tilde\psi\circ\left.\tilde\phi\right|_{\tilde\phi^{-1}(V)}$ is differentiable at $x$ and $${\rm D}\left(\tilde\psi\circ\tilde\phi\right)(x)={\rm D}\tilde\psi(u){\rm D}\tilde\phi(x)\tag3.$$ We clearly would like the left-hand side to be $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$, but I think we need what I wrote before for that.

**EDIT**: I'm using the following definition for differentiability on arbitrary sets, which can be found in [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-48101-2_21):

[image]
[image]

Comment: The differential of the identity map is the identity map on the respective tangent space, pretty much by definition.

Comment: @Thorgott What do you mean by "tangent space" here?

Comment: What do you mean by $D\phi(x)$ if there's no tangent spaces involved?

Comment: @Thorgott By $(1)$, ${\rm D}\phi(x)$ is equal to ${\rm D}\tilde\phi(x)$. As I said before, my problem is that $U\xrightarrow\psi\Omega\subseteq O\xrightarrow{\tilde\phi}\mathbb R^k$ and $\left.\tilde\psi\right|_U=\psi$, but since $U$ is not open it seems like I cannot conclude ...

Comment: @Thorgott Look, it's clear to me that $\tilde\phi\circ\psi=\operatorname{id}_U$, but the problem is that there is no $\mathbb R^k$-open set on which $\tilde\phi\circ\psi$ and $\tilde\phi\circ\tilde\psi$ coincide. But we would need this, since, by the chain rule, ${\rm D}(\tilde\phi\circ\tilde\psi)=({\rm D}\tilde\phi\circ\tilde\psi){\rm D}\tilde\psi$ on any $\mathbb R^k$-open set on which the range of $\tilde\psi$ is contained in $O$.

Comment: That is a bad definition of $D\phi(x)$, because it depends on a choice of differentiable extension $\tilde{\phi}$. Different extensions yield different derivatives, however, in the appropriate context, the restriction of the differential to a certain subspace, an appropriate tangent space, will be independent of the chosen extension. You can find a discussion of this at the very beginning of Milnor's topology. As for your given definition, the conclusion is simply wrong.

Comment: @Thorgott Please take note of my edit. I've added the precise definition I'm using.

Comment: The issue isn't the definition of differentiability, but the definition of differential/derivative.

Comment: @Thorgott And how would you define it here?

Comment: Try taking a look at the beginning of Milnor's *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint*.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you! Now I've understood what the issue is. In order to solve this problem, I'm still lacking a suitable characterization of $C^\alpha$-differentiability when the submanifold has a nonempty boundary. Maybe you can take a look at the question I've asked for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3780120/47771.

Comment: @Thorgott As I read your comment, I thought "ah, I see, there is a problem", but meanwhile, I think there is no problem: I think the tangent space definition of the derivative is only necessary for smooth maps between arbitrary manifolds (which are, in general, only topological spaces and hence the notion of Fréchet derivative is not defined for such functions). However, here the domain is a submanifold of a Banach space ($\mathbb R^d$) and the codomain is a Banach space ($E$). So, everything should work and the derivative should be independent of the extension.

Comment: @Thorgott Please take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3819961/47771. What am I missing? If I'm not wrong, I've shown there the derivative of a local extension is uniquely determined by the function itself. But didn't you say that this is a bad definition?