# Characterization of $C^\alpha$-differentiability on a submanifold with boundary

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, diffeomorphism, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, $x\in M$, $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $f:M\to E$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0\cup\{\infty\}$.

> I was able to show the following:

1. If $$f\circ\phi^{-1}\in C^\alpha(\phi(\Omega),E)\tag1$$ for some $k$-dimensional interior $C^\alpha$-chart$^2$ $(\Omega,\phi)$ of $M$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, then $f$ is $C^\alpha$-differentiable$^1$ at $x$.
2. If $f$ is  $C^\alpha$-differentiable at $x$ and $M$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^\alpha$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ without boundary for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, then there is a $k$-dimensional interior $C^\alpha$-chart $(\Omega,\phi)$ with $(1)$.

> **Question**: Are we able to show an analogous equivalent characterization of $C^\alpha$-differentiability in the case where $M$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^\alpha$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ **with boundary** for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$?

---

$^1$ If $E_i$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\Omega_i\subseteq E_i$, then $f:\Omega_1\to E_1$ is called **$C^\alpha$-differentiable at $x_1\in\Omega_1$** if $$\left.f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}$$ for some $\tilde f\in C^\alpha(O_1,E_2)$ for some $E_1$-open neighborhood $O_1$ of $x_1$. $f$ is called **$C^\alpha$-differentiable** if $f$ is $C^\alpha$ differentiable at $x_1$ for all $x_1\in\Omega_1$. If $\Omega_2\subseteq E_2$, then $f$ is called **$C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2$** if $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2$ and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $C^\alpha$-differentiable.

$^2$ $(\Omega,\phi)$ is called **$k$-dimensional $C^\alpha$-chart of $M$** if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\phi$ is a $C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times[0,\infty)$. In that case, $(\Omega,\phi)$ is called **$k$-dimensional interior $C^\alpha$-chart of $M$** if $\phi(\Omega)$ is $\mathbb R^k$-open.

Comment: I haven't written down the details, but I feel like the same proof should work. Have you tried that and, if yes, where did it fail?

Comment: @Thorgott For example, in 2.: Let $(\Omega_1,\phi)$ be a $k$-dimensional $C^\alpha$-chart of $M$ around $x$. $\Omega_1=O_1\cap M$ for some open $O_1\subseteq\mathbb R^d$. $\left.f\right|_{\Omega_2}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{\Omega_2}$ for some $\tilde f\in C^\alpha(O_2,E)$ for some $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $O_2$ of $x$ and $\Omega_2:=O_2\cap M$. $O:=O_1\cap O_2$ is $\mathbb R^d$-open and $\Omega:=\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=\Omega_1\cap O_2=O\cap M$ is $\Omega_1$-open and $M$-open. $\phi$ is an open map from $\Omega_1$ to $\phi(\Omega_1)$ and hence $U:=\phi(\Omega)$ is $\phi(\Omega_1)$-open.

Comment: @Thorgott Now, if $(\Omega_1,\phi)$ is an interior chart, then $\phi(\Omega_1)$ and thereby $U$ are $\mathbb R^d$-open. We can immediately conclude that $f\circ\left.\phi\right|_\Omega^{-1}=\tilde f\circ\left.\phi\right|_\Omega^{-1}\in C^\alpha(U,E)$. But in the general case, $\phi(\Omega_1)$ is only $\mathbb H^k$-open.

Comment: $2.$ is no issue whatsoever and I think you're making this too complicated. Any chart $\phi$ around $x$ is differentiable and the inverse $\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable at $\phi(x)$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))$, so $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable at $\phi(x)$ as composition of differentiable functions. Of course, you need to drop the requirement "interior" if your point lies on the boundary,

Comment: @Thorgott Yes, but everywhere you wrote "differentiable" above it has to be understood in the sense of "locally admitting extensions (as in the other question) which are differentiable in the ordinary sense".

Comment: Yeah, the point is that the composition of differentiable functions (in any sense) is differentiable (in this specific case, it is because the composition of local extensions is a local extensions of the composite).

Comment: @Thorgott Got it now. Thank you. However, now I don't understand why almost every reference I've consulted defines the $C^\alpha$-differentiability of $f$ in terms of $(1)$. Why doesn't one use the way easier "local extension definition"? The only reason that I could imagine is that $(1)$ still makes sense, when $M$ is not a submanifold of a Banach space, but a general topological space. In that case, the second definition cannot be used.

Comment: @Thorgott However, I stress that the references I've got in mind include such which are particularly considering submanifolds of $\mathbb R^d$ but define the $C^\alpha$-differentiability in terms of $(1)$ as well. Maybe they are doing this to familiarize the reader with the general case; I don't know. Or am I missing something?

Comment: One reference I know is Milnor's topology, which *does* use the definition in terms of local extensions. The reason why this isn't popular is just as you point out. There is no good long-term reason to only study submanifolds of Euclidean spaces rather than abstract manifolds and definition $(1)$ generalizes perfectly to those whereas the other does not. At a more abstract level, the idea to have a distinguished class of differentiable functions that one uses to "test" differentiability of an arbitrary function is important in the study of differential spaces and in aspects of sheaf theory.

Comment: @Thorgott As you surely already noticed, I've got (for some reason) a hard time to understand why things are done the way they are done. I think I've finally figured it out now and probably will ask for verification of my understanding in a separate post tomorrow. But to tease what I've got in mind: I think, while both differentiability definitions are equivalent in the case where the ambient space is a Banach space, even in that case the derivative is not well-defined. I really struggled to understand why the other notion of differentiability solves this problem,

Comment: @Thorgott since I thought the we would encounter the same problem: To be precise, it statates that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable (in the local extension sense) for some chart $(\Omega,\phi)$ around $x$. Now I thought, the same problem would occur, since $\phi(\Omega)$ is **not** open in $\mathbb R^k$; only in $\mathbb H^k$.

Comment: @Thorgott But now I think the reason is that it can actually be shown (by the same argument as for the curves that we've discussed before) that the derivative of a $C^1$-differentiable function from $\mathbb H^k$ to any Banach space is actually uniquely-determined; even at the boundary. Do you agree so far?

Comment: @Thorgott Could you take a look at the other question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781630/47771)? I haven't found a single reference concerning this issue, but it is mentioned that the derivative is independent of the choice here in Definition 2.1.4: https://aalldridge.github.io/assets/lectures/2007-ana4/lnss07.pdf#page=30.

Comment: @Thorgott I just came across this question and wondered whether I'm missing something or you didn't noticed it as you read the question, but (2.) should be obviously wrong. We should only be able to conlcude that $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is $C^1$-differentiable **at $\phi(x)$**or am I missing something?

Comment: @Thorgott Please take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3819961/47771. What am I missing? If I'm not wrong, I've shown there the derivative of a local extension is uniquely determined by the function itself.

Comment: I think that's not an issue. If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, it is differentiable in a neighborhood of $x$, so any chart lying within that neighborhood will satisfy $(1)$ by the previous argument. As for your new question, what you seem to have shown is that the derivative of a local extension is uniquely determined *on the tangent space at that point*, which is true and, if I recall correctly, something I mentioned before.

Comment: @Thorgott In a comment below [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779844/if-phi-is-a-homeomorphism-and-both-phi-and-phi-1-extend-to-different?noredirect=1&lq=1) you wrote it would be a bad definition to define the pushforward to be $T_x(f)v:={\rm D}\tilde f(x)v$, for $v∈T_x\:M$, where $\tilde f$ is a $C^1$-extension of $f$ at $x$. Maybe we misunderstood each other and what you were actually trying to tell me is that ${\rm D}\tilde f(x)$ is not uniquely determined by $f$; only its restriction $\left.{\rm D}\tilde f(x)\right|_{T_x\:M}$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

Comment: What I said is a bad definition is $Df(x)=D\tilde{f}(x)$, because it's not well-defined. The point is indeed that, while $D\tilde{f}(x)$ is not well-defined, $D\tilde{f}(x)\vert_{T_xM}$ is.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you for clarifying. Then we actually misunderstood each other. Could you take a look at my related question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817136/47771.