# Uniqueness of the derivative of a differentiable function on a non-open set

Tags: differential-topology, frechet-derivative

If $E_i$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\Omega_1\subseteq E_1$, then $f:\Omega_1\to E_2$ is called **$C^1$-differentiable at $x_1\in\Omega_1$** if $$\left.f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}$$ for some $\tilde f\in C^1(O_1,E_2)$ for some $E_1$-open neighborhood $O_1$ of $x_1$.

> Is $${\rm D}f(x_1):={\rm D}\tilde f(x_1)\tag1$$ well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $\tilde f$?

I would say, it obviously should be, but the discussion below [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3779844/47771) raised some doubts.

Maybe I'm missing subtlety but if $\hat O_1$ and $\hat f$ are other choices for $O_1$ and $\tilde f$, then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that the $E_1$-open ball around $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$ is contained in $O_1\cap\hat O_1$ and it should clearly hold \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\left\|\left({\rm D}\tilde f(x_1)-{\rm D}\hat f(x_1)\right)h_1\right\|_{E_2}\\&=\left\|\frac{\hat f(x_1+h_1)-\hat f(x_1)-{\rm D}\hat f(x_1)h_1}{\left\|h_1\right\|_{E_1}}-\frac{\tilde f(x_1+h_1)-\tilde f(x_1)-{\rm D}\tilde f(x_1)h_1}{\left\|h_1\right\|_{E_1}}\right\|_{E_2}\left\|h_1\right\|_{E_1}\end{split}\end{equation} for all $h_1\in E_1\setminus\{0\}$ with $\left\|h\right\|_{E_1}<\varepsilon$, which tends to $0$ as $h\to0$. So, it should hold $${\rm D}\tilde f(x_1)={\rm D}\hat f(x_1)\tag2.$$ What am I missing?

Comment: Without any hypothesis about $\Omega_1$ it won't work. What if $\Omega_1$ is a single point?

Comment: What is $E_i$ and $E_2$ doing in the question?

Comment: No, because $\tilde{f}$ need only agree with $f$ on the restriction to $\Omega_1$. There may be many such $\tilde{f}$s.

Comment: @user10354138 What do you mean? The Fréchet derivative is defined for functions from an open subset of a Banach space ($E_1$) to another Banach space $(E_2)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Don't know what I was thinking. For some strange reason I thought $f$ and $\tilde f,\hat f$ would agree on $O_1\cap\hat O_1$ ...

Comment: But your $f$ goes from $\Omega_1$ to $E_1$ in your first line, not a subset of $E_1$ to $E_2$..

Comment: @user10354138 $\Omega_1\subseteq E_2$. The only "problem" is that I don't used $\Omega_2\subseteq E_2$. (I've written $\Omega_i\subseteq E_i$ as a shorthand for $\Omega_1\subseteq E_1,\Omega_2\subseteq E_2$.)

Comment: No, there are more problems than that.  You define $\tilde{f}\in C^1(O_1,E_2)$ which is of course incompatible with the $f\colon\Omega_1\to E_1$ -- you are comparing maps to different Banach spaces.

Comment: @user10354138 That was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f\colon\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2,\,(x,0)\mapsto(x,0)$. Consider $\operatorname{id}\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\pi\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2,\,(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$. Both of these are differentiable (smooth even) functions and clearly $\operatorname{id}\vert_{\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}}=f=\pi\vert_{\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}}$. However, $D\operatorname{id}(x)=\operatorname{id}\neq\pi=D\pi(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yeah, see my comment to @copper.hat below the question. I'm still a bit confused about how things need to be properly defined, which let me made this strange mistake ...

Comment: One of the main applications I've got in mind is that $f$ is a curve on an interval of the form $\Omega_1=(-\varepsilon,0]$ or $\Omega_1=[0,\varepsilon)$ and $x_1=0$. In that case, ${\rm D}f(0)$ as defined by $(1)$ should be independent of the extension by the identity above equation $(2)$. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, this should be true for any codimension $0$ submanifold with boundary. In this specific case, the existence of a $C^1$-extension is equivalent to the existence of the right-hand derivative at $x_1=0$ and the continuity of the derivative on $[0,\epsilon)$. Then $Df(0)$ has to agree with the right-hand derivative for any $C^1$ extension $f$ by continuity of the derivative. A similar argument establishes the general case.

Comment: But $D\mathrm{id}=D\pi$ on the domain of $f$. Isn't that all that matters?