# Why can't we define the pushforward $T_x(f)v$ to be ${\rm D}\tilde f(x)v$, where $\tilde f$ is any $C^1$-extension of $f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold, pushforward

> I don't understand why we cannot define the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) using a local $C^1$-extension.

To be precise, let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, $x\in M$ and $f:M\to\mathbb R$ be $C^1$-differentiable at $x$. Then, by definition, $$T_x(f)v=(f\circ\gamma)'(0),\tag1$$ where $\gamma$ is an arbitrary $C^1$-curve on $M$ through $x$ with $\gamma'(0)=v\in T_x\:M$.

That's fine and I know how we can show that $(1)$ does not depend on the choice of $\gamma$. However, let's take a step back: By assumption, $$\left.f\right|_{O\:\cap\:M}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{O\:\cap\:M}\tag2$$ for some $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $O$ of $x$ and some $f\in C^1(O)$. Now let $(I,\gamma)$ be a $C^1$-curve on $M$ through $x$ and $v:=\gamma'(0)$. Since $\gamma$ is continuous and $\Omega:=O\cap\partial M$ is $\partial M$-open, $\gamma^{-1}(\Omega)$ is $I$-open and hence $$\tilde I:=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\cap I\subseteq\gamma^{-1}(\Omega)\tag3$$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Most importantly, $\tilde\gamma:=\left.\gamma\right|_{\tilde I}$ is again a $C^1$-curve on $\Omega$ (hence on $M\supseteq\Omega$) through $x$ and hence $$T_x(f)v=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=(\tilde f\circ\tilde\gamma)'(0)={\rm D}\tilde f(\tilde\gamma(0))\tilde\gamma'(0)={\rm D}\tilde f(x)v,\tag4$$ where ${\rm D}\tilde f(x)$ is the ordinary Fréchet derivative of $\tilde f$ at $x$.

> So, ${\rm D}\tilde f(x)v$ does not depend on the choice of $\tilde f$ (since the left-hand side of $(4)$ does not). What am I missing? Why don't we define $$T_x(f)v:={\rm D}\tilde f(x)v\tag5$$ for any $C^1$-extension $\tilde f$ of $f$ at $x$ and $v\in T_x\:M$?

---

**Definition 1**: Let $E_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\Omega_1\subseteq E_1$. Then $f:\Omega_1\to E_2$ is called **$C^1$-differentiable at $x_1$** if $$\left.f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{O_1\:\cap\:\Omega_1}\tag0$$ fomr some $\tilde f\in C^1(O_1,E_2)$ for some $E_1$-open neighborhood $O_1$ of $x_1$. $(O_1,\tilde f)$ is called **$C^1$-extension of $f$ at $x_1$**.

**Definition 2**: Let $M$ be a subset of a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $x\in M$. $(I,\gamma)$ is called **$C^1$-curve on $M$ through $x$** if $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a nontrivial interval with $0\in I$ and $\gamma:I\to M$ is $C^1$-differentiable with $\gamma(0)=x$. Let $$T_x\:M:=\{\gamma'(0):\gamma\text{ is a }C^1\text{-curve on }M\text{ through }x\}.$$

Comment: @Matematleta Well, yes. That's the point. Every reference that I've consulted defined the pushforward in terms of curves and I assume that there is a good reason for this. I thought the reason would be that defining it to be the Fréchet derivative of a local extension would be impossible, since the derivative would depend on the choice of the extension.

Comment: You can prove equivalence directly by using the local structure of $M$ as a submanifold (either a parametrization or a slice chart). The difference of two extensions will vanish and therefore has zero directional derivatives along the submanifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just to be sure, with "you can prove equivalence" you mean the equivalence between the definitions $(1)$ and $(5)$, right?

Comment: I should have just said well-definedness of (5), but yes.

Comment: @Matematleta At least in my opinion, $(5)$ is more intuitive than $(1)$. However, isn't the actual reason for using $(1)$ instead of $(5)$ that $(1)$ applies to the more general case when $M$ is an abstract manifold (hence just a topological space) which is not embedded into an ambient Banach space, while $(5)$ obviously needs an ambient Banach space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for clarifying. Do you agree to what I wrote in my response to Matematleta?

Comment: Yes. With abstract manifolds, curves are the way to go. Derivations are most useful, but you need a $C^\infty$ structure for that to work out well. That’s a different story.

Comment: @Matematleta For $C^1$ functions the space of derivations at $p$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @Matematleta: When you apply Hadamard, you need to know that if $f\in C^k$, then your derivation acts on $\sum x^i g_i(x)$, but now $g_i$ are only in $C^{k-1}$, so how does the derivation act?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, got it, thank you!

Comment: @TedShifrin I think my whole confusion about the "tangential gradient" in the other question was due to the fact that I didn't noticed that it should be simply the composition of the pushforward with the projection onto the tangent space. Since I want to make sure, that I didn't missed anything (which is not unlikely), I've asked a better phrased question for what: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822152/47771. It would be great if you could take a look.